# Custom OAuth in Unity linking to Parse Server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oauth-2.0, parse-platform

I am using Unity with Parse Server and now wants to be able to link a user with OAuth.

This is what I am trying so far, but with no luck.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class DGUOAuth
{
    public string dguId = "";
    public string access_token = "";
}

DGUOAuth auth = new DGUOAuth()
{
   access_token = "F12w06Ddqx1k5qj75JQWRZmzh16Zgf05wHExNnHAnh8",
   dguId = "25-1999"
};

System.Threading.CancellationToken canceltoken;

Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
data.Add("authData", auth);

Debug.Log("Ready for linking the user!");

DataManager.user.LinkWithAsync("DGU", data, canceltoken).ContinueWith(t =>
{
   if (t.IsFaulted)
   {
       Debug.Log("Faulted: " + t.Exception);
       // Errors from Parse Cloud and network interactions
       using (IEnumerator<Exception> enumerator = t.Exception.InnerExceptions.GetEnumerator())
       {
           if (enumerator.MoveNext())
           {
               ParseException error = (ParseException)enumerator.Current;
               Debug.Log(error.Message);
               // error.Message will contain an error message
               // error.Code will return "OtherCause"
           }
       }
   }
   else
   {
       Debug.Log("User is linked");
   }
});
```

Nothing happens and I only get "Ready for linking the user!" but no logs after that?! The documentation for `LinkWithAsync` and Unity is almost not existing...

Really hope someone can help me on this. Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

----- EDIT -----

Now, added a `Debug.Log` just after `t.isFaulted` and get this log:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentException: Unable to encode objects of type DGUOAuth

Not sure how to solve this. I do not get any error logs in the Parse server logs.

Comment: Do you see anything in your Parse Server logs? Would you mind to put one more `Debug.log()` right after t.isFaulted?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo Added a debug.log af t.isFaulted and got this: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentException: Unable to encode objects of type DGUOAuth - Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Would you mind to share how you are initializing the `data` var? I guess it has an object of class DGUOAuth that you probably created and the Parse SDK does not "know" how to encode this object.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo Sorry for the delay and the missing script. Added the initializing of data in the original post.

Comment: can you share the DGUOAuth class? Is it serializable?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo Sorry for that... Added the DGUAuth class to original post, and yes it is serializable

Comment: I've just looked at the Parse SDK and it looks you can't pass a custom object even if it is serializable (https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-dotNET/blob/f68bde1e89264df183f863c5b601633d2d5dd5ed/Parse/Infrastructure/Utilities/JsonUtilities.cs#L412). So you will have to pass a dictionary to the `data.Add("authData", auth)` call. Maybe you can add a `toDictionary()` functions o your `DGUOAuth` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue

The error is basically coming from [`JsonUtility.Encode`](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-dotNET/blob/f68bde1e89264df183f863c5b601633d2d5dd5ed/Parse/Infrastructure/Utilities/JsonUtilities.cs#L334)

> ```
> public static string Encode(IDictionary<string, object> dict)
> {
>     if (dict == null)
>         throw new ArgumentNullException();
>     if (dict.Count == 0)
>         return "{}";
>     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("{");
>     foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in dict)
>     {
>         builder.Append(Encode(pair.Key));
>         builder.Append(":");
>         builder.Append(Encode(pair.Value));
>         builder.Append(",");
>     }
>     builder[builder.Length - 1] = '}';
>     return builder.ToString();
> }
> ```

where `builder.Append(Encode(pair.Value));` then tries to call [`Encode(object)`](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-dotNET/blob/f68bde1e89264df183f863c5b601633d2d5dd5ed/Parse/Infrastructure/Utilities/JsonUtilities.cs#L376)

> ```
>     public static string Encode(object obj)
>     {
>         if (obj is IDictionary<string, object> dict)
>             return Encode(dict);
>         if (obj is IList<object> list)
>             return Encode(list);
>         if (obj is string str)
>         {
>             str = escapePattern.Replace(str, m =>
>             {
>                 switch (m.Value[0])
>                 {
>                     case '\\':
>                         return "\\\\";
>                     case '\"':
>                         return "\\\"";
>                     case '\b':
>                         return "\\b";
>                     case '\f':
>                         return "\\f";
>                     case '\n':
>                         return "\\n";
>                     case '\r':
>                         return "\\r";
>                     case '\t':
>                         return "\\t";
>                     default:
>                         return "\\u" + ((ushort) m.Value[0]).ToString("x4");
>                 }
>             });
>             return "\"" + str + "\"";
>         }
>         if (obj is null)
>             return "null";
>         if (obj is bool)
>             return (bool) obj ? "true" : "false";
>         if (!obj.GetType().GetTypeInfo().IsPrimitive)
>             throw new ArgumentException("Unable to encode objects of type " + obj.GetType());
>         return Convert.ToString(obj, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
>     }
> ```

so without knowing that thing at all it looks like it simply expects an `IDictionary<string, object>` where the `value` can only be of the types

- `IDictionary<string, object>` (where the value type again underlies the same type restrictions)
- `IList<object>` (where the element type again underlies the same restrictions)
- `string`
- `bool`
- primitive types (`int`, `short`, `ulong`, `float`, etc)

your given class `DGUOAuth` is neither of these => `ArgumentException`.

---

#### Solution(s)

So I would simply not use your `DGUOAuth` class at all but simply construct according dictionary either directly as

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"authData" , "{\"access_token\" : \"F12w06Ddqx1k5qj75JQWRZmzh16Zgf05wHExNnHAnh8\", \"dguId\" : \"25-1999\"}"}
};
```

or if you want to as

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"authData" , new Dictionary<string, object>
                  {
                      {"access_token", "F12w06Ddqx1k5qj75JQWRZmzh16Zgf05wHExNnHAnh8"}, 
                      {"dguId", "25-1999"}
                  }
    }
};
```

where of course you can fill in the values also dynamically from variables if needed.

The alternative would be to make sure that your `DGUOAuth` returns such a dictionary this makes it maybe easier for you if you need to pass this around a lot or configure it via the Inspector

```
[System.Serializable]
public class DGUOAuth
{
    public string dguId = "";
    public string access_token = "";

    public DGUOauth(string id, string token)
    {
        dguId = id;
        access_token = token;
    }

    public IDictionary<string, object> ToDictionary()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"access_token", access_token}, 
            {"dguId", dguId}
        };
    }
}
```

and then use it like

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"authData", new DGUOauth("25-1999", "F12w06Ddqx1k5qj75JQWRZmzh16Zgf05wHExNnHAnh8").ToDictionary()}
};
```

or actually implements according interface [`IDictionary<string, object>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2) which in my eyes is a lot of **overkill** for this little task.

---

I'm not even sure if you need that field name `authData` there or if it rather simply would expect

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
   {"access_token", "F12w06Ddqx1k5qj75JQWRZmzh16Zgf05wHExNnHAnh8"}, 
   {"dguId", "25-1999"}
};
```

but that's something you will have to try.